# Creating a secure code tester application in PHP

Tags: php, security, automated-tests

I'm making a web code tester application in PHP which is cappable of executing PHP and MySql codes directly. This gives the users the ability to test their webcodes on my website right away. However, I imagine such code brings a lot of (possible) security issues, as it just executes any code written inside a textbox by the user. So I was wondering: how do I make such a code tester to be secure? What I was doing so far is preg_matching all 'dangerous' PHP functions out of the user input code ( e.g. the function CHMOD ), but I'm not sure if it's realistic to do this for all possibly harming functions in PHP.

Any suggestions on how to make my script secure?

Thanks in advanced,
Skyfe.

Comment: I'm afraid this is next to impossible to do without having a private dedicated server on which you can sandbox everything. Having direct access to a mysql database also serves some extreme security risks. It is probably better to whitelist functions then to blacklist them, as hackers/crackers will otherwise always be step ahead of you! 
Also, make sure you log EVERYTHING, because every failed attempt to get t your system is 1 step closer to getting to your system!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really have an "answer" for you, but hopefully can offer some advice and a few things to think about...

This doesn't sound like an easy task.  And the approach you're taking so far of stripping out "dangerous" code is *definitely* not a good idea.  There's a *lot* of overlap between "code that can be made dangerous" and "standard code your users will want to be able to use."

It sounds like this task is going to run a lot deeper than just the code itself.  The process on the server that executes the code will need to be sandboxed, the server itself should be sandboxed, etc.  Some questions to ask yourself:

- What user account is used on the server when executing this code?
- What permissions does this account have?  Can it affect *anything* else on the server?
- What can this server do on the network?  Does the rest of the network trust anything coming from this server?
- etc.

For example, is the PHP code being executed under, say, the same user context as your web server?  Apache, for example?  If so then user-submitted code could potentially be used to reconfigure your web server, opening it up for more vulnerabilities.  Does it run as root or have trusted access to anything that runs as root?

The security implications of executing user-submitted code on your server go far beyond just the web application which accepts the code.

Comment: Thanks for you response. I as well thought preg_matching would limit as well the amount of actual valid codes to be ran by the user if I'd want to make it real secure, however this would not be such a big deal is it would basicly only be meant to test codes of tutorials from my website. 

Concerning the server itself, I don't really have much knowledge about that, but would it be possible to get in contact with my host and let them 'limit' the permissions of users to read-only access for example? And going further than just CHMOD'ing it, as that wouldn't fix it right?

Comment: @Skyfe: If you're using a hosting service then you'll definitely want to contact them for at least one of two reasons: 1) They may have a setup for something like this and may be sandboxing everything you do by default anyway.  2) They may explicitly disallow this and you may want to avoid getting in trouble.

Comment: Thanks, I'll contact my host about this first and then reconsider.